# Is there a way to save a class's state in a specific moment in time?

Tags: python, class, static

In Python 3, is there anyway to create a variable that can hold an unchanging state of a class at a certain moment in time? If there is, I must be missing the terminology for it. I also am not talking about static, my attributes need to be able to change.

It would work like so:

```
class_save = [Class(a,b,c).attribute, Class(d,e,f).attribute]

static_save = class_save

#if I do this
class_save.remove(static_save[1])

#class_save should now equal [Class(a,b,c).attribute]
#static_save should still be equal to [Class(a,b,c).attribute, Class(d,e,f).attribute]
```

Comment: Can you talk in more plain language terms about the problem you are trying to solve?    For example are you trying to implement "undo" and "redo" in some sort of application?

Comment: `class_save` is a list,  `class_save[:]` is a copy of that list.  `del alist[1]` removes an item from a list.

Comment: `Class(a,b,c)` looks like a class instance, not a 'state'.  `Class[a,b,c).attribute` could be any sort of object.  So `class_save` is just a list of unspecified objects.

Comment: it looks like you are just asking hot to copy an object. Is that what you want?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm still kinda new to programming so I'm trying to understand new words to explain it. I essentially want to be able to change some instance of a class, but still have a copy of the instance somewhere that refers to it from before I changed it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm coding a chess game, and am implementing the moves for a rook. I have a function that makes a list of all the possible rook moves, then checks the list to make sure none of the moves are blocked by other "ChessPiece" classes. I need a way to refer to the original list created by the function, even after I removed some elements from it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck So I guess it would be kind of like making some list `x = [a,b,c]` then storing it in `x_copy = x`, so  that even if I change `x` I can still refer to the original list in `x_copy`. Except, I need to be able to do this for class instances in the list.

Comment: Yea, you just want a copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment,  you said:

> I'm coding a chess game, and am implementing the moves for a rook. I have a function that makes a list of all the possible rook moves, then checks the list to make sure none of the moves are blocked by other "ChessPiece" classes. I need a way to refer to the original list created by the function, even after I removed some elements from it.

OK, so you have an original list of moves:

```
all_moves = [move1, move2, move3, ...]
```

Then you filter it:

```
valid_moves = [move for move in all_moves if is_valid_move(move)]
```

This gives you two lists: the second contains references to a subset of the elements of the first list.  There is no deep copy required, and no excessive memory allocation.

Comment: I think my issue is in establishing the `is_valid_move()` function. I will work more on trying to see if I can find a more elegant solution for the checking. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean object serialization? Using the `pickle` library you can do `pickle.dumps(object)` to serialize and `pickle.loads(serialized_object)` to deserialize.

Answer (score 1):

If you a full copy in memory you need a **deep-copy**

`copy.deepcopy(x)`

If you want it frozen on disk `pickle.dump` it.

Comment: I see bhargava also gave a similar answer, I've been trying to read up on it, but can you possibly explain the difference between creating a deep-copy vs serialization?

Comment: @SignalProcessed Serialization is the conversion of an in memory object which may be randomly accessed, to data which must be accessed in a contiguous(streamed) fashion, such as when saving to disk or pushing through a socket.  A deep copy copies the entire in memory object graph to a different location in memory, it doesn't touch the disk at all.  The difference between a deep and shallow copy is that a shallow copy does not recurse to call copy on reference objects, so only the root of the object graph would be copied.